# Aws amplify signIn method returns Incorrect username and password while federatedSignIn (Hosted UI) works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools, amplifyjs

I am using aws cognito for authentication. I have two environment for development and production hosted in two different region.

**Development in us-east-1**

**Production in us-west-2**

I want to change cognito hosted UI authentication (federatedSignIn) to custom aws-amplify signIn. Development configuration works fine while signIn in both hosted UI authentication and custom signIn aws-amplify. In production environment hosted UI works fine while signIn but custom signIn returns

```
{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Incorrect username or password."}
```

for already existing users.

The only different configuration in development and production environment is

**Development -> Always**

**Production -> No**

Does this configuration effects custom signIn ?

[image]

aws-amplify configure

```
Amplify.configure({
  aws_project_region: *******************,
  aws_cognito_region: *******************,
  aws_user_pools_id: *******************,
  aws_user_pools_web_client_id: *******************,
  authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
  oauth: {
    domain: *******************,
    scope: ['email', 'openid', 'profile'],
    redirectSignIn: `*******************`,
    redirectSignOut: `*******************`,
    responseType: 'code',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am able to replicate the issue. The issue was wrong POOL_ID. Wrong POOL_ID doesn't effect hosted UI signIn but does effect effect amplify login, that's why its return 'Incorrect username and password' for correct email and password.

Comment: Thanks. Took me hours to figure out I forgot to change my environment variable for the prod version.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```js
authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
```

to

```js
authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
```

This changes the authentication flow [to a standard built in flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#Built-in-authentication-flow-and-challenges) as opposed to the more configurable Auth challenge flow.

I've not quite tracked down why I can't use auth-challenge flow, answers in the comments..